# High short term fuel trim on one side when starting car?

Tags: exhaust, o2-sensor, ford-panther-platform

2003 Ford Crown Victoria
V8 Engine
Dual exhaust
2 cats & O2 sensors per side

Since some time last year I've been getting an error code throw up, with seemingly no regularity:

**P2197 - O2 stuck lean - Bank 2 Sensor 1**

First thought was to replace the sensor, so that's new but didn't fix the problem. It doesn't happen much when it's hot and dry, primarily when it's cold and/or damp out.

I recently picked up a bluetooth OBD-II live scanner, and looking at the values as I drive, I've learned that, when it does happen, the O2 voltages are pretty much normal, though they'll kind of "stick" on B2-S1 to a number (different each time) whereas B1-S1 will fluctuate normally. I've seen anywhere from `.06v` to `.94v`

At the same time, the short-term fuel trim will lock even tighter to a number, and stay that way until it all clears. Most common is `32.8%`, but there is some variance from about `30%` - `55%`.

It'll start normally, then within about 10-30 seconds lock onto these numbers, stay that way for about a minute, then return to normal ranges for both voltage and trim. If the car is started cold then it won't throw a code, but if it's still warm then it will often trigger the MIL and store the freeze-frame data.

Any ideas on what's actually wrong, how to fix it, or more diagnostics to do?

My #1 thought is a vacuum leak somewhere, and I have an idea of which chunk of hose it *might* be, but I haven't had a chance to find a new one to replace it with. My other thought is the computer having some values stored wrong that I would need to reset (just disconnect the battery). I only thought of this one a day ago and haven't had the time to do it yet and still go on a long enough drive to relearn shift points.

Answer (score 2):

From everything I see in this paper, it seems that it may be related to a vacuum leak.

tl;dr - Check your vacuum lines and make sure none of them are cracked.

[image: P2197 Page 1]
[image: P2197 Page 2]
[image: P2197 Page 3]

Here are some more ideas [from here](http://www.modularfords.com/f79/p2197-o2-sensor-signal-stuck-lean-93366/):

> ## P2197
>
> Lack of HO2S-21 Switch, Sensor Indicates Lean Detailed
>   Description A heated oxygen sensor (HO2S) indicating lean at the end
>   of a test is trying to correct for an over-rich condition. The test
>   fails when the fuel control system no longer detects switching for a
>   calibrated amount of time.
>
> Possible Causes:
>
> Electrical:
>
> - Short to VPWR in the harness or HO2S.
> - Water in the harness connector.
> - Open/shorted HO2S circuit.
> - Corrosion or poor mating terminals and wiring.
> - Damaged HO2S.
> - Damaged powertrain control module (PCM).
>
> Fuel System:
>
> - Excessive fuel pressure.
> - Leaking/contaminated fuel injectors.
> - Leaking fuel pressure regulator.
> - Low fuel pressure or running out of fuel.
> - Vapor recovery system. Induction System:
> - Air leaks after the mass air flow (MAF) sensor.
> - Vacuum Leaks.
> - PCV system.
> - Improperly seated engine oil dipstick.
>
> EGR System:
>
> - Leaking gasket.
> - Stuck EGR valve.
> - Leaking diaphragm or EVR.
>
> Base Engine:
>
> - Oil overfill.
> - Cam Timing.
> - Cylinder compression.
> - Exhaust leaks before or near the HO2S(s)

Comment: If it's just on a single bank, vacuum leak is the first place to look for sure.